# why android application logo is not coming in 5.0 version?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-version

After updating my device's android version(lollipop), my app's logo is not displaying in lollipop version. and color of action bar has changed.

I am using following theme in my application

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"
```

What would be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm.. that style is follows device's default style.

If you want same style for all devices, set style like this. `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`

Then you can see style with app logo like as before for all devices & versions.

Or if you want Material style. you might be using Toolbar.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to do few changes:

parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" need to applied in your

style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>
</resources>
```

And then goto

File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "appcompat"

then

Project-> properties->Android. Select tab library "Add" and choose "appCompat"